# JS ActiveXObject On Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser, activexobject

I have Old ASP Project that depends on ActiveXObject 
and now I want to make my project cross-browser and work on chrome in additional to ie
Can I Find any Plugin that makes chrome support ActiveXObject
*Note* I tried to use DOMParser() instead of ActiveXObject but it's not working fine

Comment: You should ask about the real problem you've at hands, not about [an imaginary solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for it.

Comment: Ok so how to make ActiveXObject run on chrome?

Comment: That should already be obvious, you can't. Instead, ask a new question about why your DOMParser code doesn't work. Create a reproducible code example, and explain in details, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is only supported by IE - the other browsers use a plugin architecture called NPAPI. However, there's a cross-browser plugin framework called [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't support ActiveXObject. You could use [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en) in Chrome.

IE Tab exactly emulates IE by using the IE rendering engine directly within Chrome.  This will enable you to use ActiveX controls and test your web pages with different versions of IE.